# Generated DDL doesn't match with CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: mysql, innodb, python, sqlalchemy

I'm using MySQL with InnoDB engine. I create a new table that contains a foreign key, eg:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    my_id VARCHAR(15), 
    house_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(house_id) REFERENCES houses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

When I use a DB tool such as DBeaver to see the details of my database and this table, I see that my foreign key `house_id` is missing the `ON DELETE CASCADE` setting.

DBeaver also shows the DDL for this table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `my_id` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `house_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `house_id` (`house_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rooms_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`house_id`) REFERENCES `houses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Why does the DDL have the extra line `KEY 'house_id' ('house_id').`? This extra line also causes my foreign key to show 2 `house_id` columns in my DBeaver table viewer. If I get rid of this, my `ON DELETE CASCADE` gets set correctly.

I'm using an ORM so I don't have control of the `CREATE TABLE` statement, so I'm just trying to at least understand what's going on here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says (emphasis mine):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. **Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist**.

In other words, this is an expected, documented behaviour. If DBeaver cannot see a difference between table constraints and its indexes, may be choose some other tool.